# Heat Equation - Setup & Plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

The task is is:

[Heat Equation Question given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ix21z.png)

[Plots I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyvU1.png)

Generate a 2D plot where you show the temperature profiles at t = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 using 5 and 100 modes for α = 0.5 (in other words, rather than calculate an infinite sum, only sum the first 5 or 100 terms).

I'm new to python so I don't know how to tackle this. This is the code I have so far

```
x = np.arange(0,4)
n = np.arange(1,6)
t = np.arange(0,6)
def fun(x,n,t):
  l = 0
  for i in x:
    for j in n:
        for k in t:
            x = i
            n = j
            t = k
            z = []
            alpha = 0.5
            a = 8/m.pi
            b = m.sin((2*n - 1)*x)
            c = (2*n - 1)**2
            d = m.exp(-(2*n - 1)**2 *alpha**2 *t)
            T = a*(b/c)*d
            l += T
    z.append(T)
  return z
```

This does not run. Could you help me generate the 2D plot I need?
print(fun(x,n,t))

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your code:

1. you always reset `z` in the inner loop
2. the indent of `z.append(T)` marks it as being in the first loop, although T is calculated in the inner loop.

I think this is what you want:

```python
def fun(x,n,t):
  l = 0
  z = []
  for i in x:
    for j in n:
      for k in t:
        x = i
        # ... insert your other calculations here...
        T = a*(b/c)*d
        l += T
        z.append(T)
  return z
```